# Angular 2 filter by exact values (strict equality)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-pipe

I have created a pipe which filters data based on user input search in angular 2.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterName',
  pure:false
})
export class FilterNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchTerm: any): any[] {
    if (!searchTerm) return items;
    return items.filter(function(item){
      if(item.fullNme == null){
        return null;
      }else {
        return item.fullNme.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
      }
    })
  }

}

JSON : 
{ name: "Peter Martha",   age: 2 },
{ name: "Martha, Pablo ",   age: 55 },
{ name: "Linda Peter",   age: 20 },
```

The above filter works fine.I want one  which filters based on first input string.When i look for "P/p" it should display only **Peter Martha** , but not **Linda Peter** or **Martha Pablo**.Can some one tell what am i doing wrong or what changes should be done.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`String.startsWith()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) function

```
return item.fullNme.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```